# ERROR : cannot import name preprocessor_pb2 google cloud

Tags: object, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I am having this error when running tensorflow object detection on google cloud :

I am having an error also :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", 
line 174, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", 
line 72, in _run_code exec code in 
run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/object_detection/train.py", 
line 49, in <module> from 
object_detection import trainer File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/object_detection/trainer.py", 
line 27, in <module> from 
object_detection.builders import preprocessor_builder File 
"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/object_detection/builders/preprocessor_builder.py", 
line 21, 
in <module> from object_detection.protos import preprocessor_pb2 
ImportError: cannot import name preprocessor_pb2
```

Any help to fix this ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.Could you rephrase your question according to  [this helpful instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

f you are on windows OS, From the command prompt change directory to research(parent of object_detection) Folder run the following. Change the commands accordingly based on the OS you are on

1) protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

2) SET PYTHONPATH=%cd%;%cd%\slim

Then launch the notebook from same command line and try to run.